# How to ensure my doctype is XHTML 1.0 Strict

Tags: xhtml, maps, markup, doctype, transitional

While working on an XHTML 1.0 Strict page, I discovered that `iframe` was deprecated. I've done some research, and replaced it with an `object` tag.

```
<object id="gmap" type="text/html" data="https://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=216725582357492079329.0004cf99c633289e8b190&amp;hl=en&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;ll=34.870479,-40.172607&amp;spn=34.201734,120.673828&amp;output=embed"></object>
```

It validated, but as HTML 4.0 transitional. How do I validate it as XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Comment: please add your code too...It will be better

Answer (score 0):

The W3C validator does not validate the content embedded in an `iframe` or `object` tag. If you want to know how to make it XHTML 1.0 Strict, start with a valid XHTML 1.0 Strict document, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div><object data="http://example.com"></object></div>
</body>
</html>
```

then add your markup without invalidating it.